# Checking lm() function

Tags: r, plot, lm, loglog

Why this is not the same?

```
y2=log10(Standards$`IL2 median`)
x2=c(0,log10(concentration[2:10]))
y2
[1] 2.495544 2.773055 2.982271 3.192567 3.668572 3.706974 4.151799
[8] 4.450357 4.776396 4.833561
x2
[1] 0.000000 1.301030 1.602060 1.903090 2.193125 2.494850 2.795880
[8] 3.096910 3.397940 3.698970
fitil2=lm(y2~x2)
coef(fitil2)

(Intercept)          x2 
  2.0688728   0.7268491
```

AND

```
fitil=lm(Standards$`IL2 median`~concentration,log="xy")
Call:
lm(formula = Standards$`IL2 median` ~ concentration, log = "xy")

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)  concentration  
      3239.47          15.13
```

Concentration has a zero, that's why I have excluded it in x2.

Can you help me?

Comment: the log in your second lm model is not correct syntax (it looks kind if like a hybrid plot command)

Comment: ... in fact did the `log="xy"` give a warning?

Comment: ps; you will find it much easier going forward if you use the `data=Standards` argument in `lm` instead of `Standards$`IL2 median` and also much easier if you use syntactically correct R names -- see `?make.names`